# How to refer to an Ambassador Extraordinary and Plenipotentiary in speech?/¿Cómo referirme a una Embajadora Plenipotenciaria al hablarle?

Tags: méxico

I live in Mexico and yesterday I phoned Romania's Embassy asking for information on whether they can sell me books in Romanian (exceedingly rare here!) and how to study the university over there (I'm 17 and will finish high school in a couple months, but we're moving away and I need the info within two weeks), get a scholarship, etc. Now that I got over my natural shyness and spoke to them in my (terrible) Romanian, they were not rude like other times when they would even hang up on me. They still claimed not to know anything and that I should write an e-mail (which I have done and have received no reply) asking for a personal appointment with...TA-DAAAAA!!!...the Ambassador herself, Her Excellency (I think!?!?) doamna Ana Voicu. I wrote the e-mail in Spanish, using the most formal and polite language I've ever used, telling her that it's my dream to study in her country and that I would like the info because we're moving away, and requesting the appointment; I then sent it to her secretaries' e-mail address which is the Embassy's official address, but it was addressed directly to her.
Do you think she will give me the appointment within the week, as the guy to whom I spoke told me? (I've learned through bitter experience that people don't always mean what they say!) How should I be dressed, speak, refer to her, etc.? (We will likely be speaking in Spanish.) I have a blue streak in my hair (no piercings or anything), should I hide it? Should I make an attempt to speak to her in my awful Romanian so she sees that this matters to me and that I'm working hard toward my goal? How should I word my request? It seems to me that speaking to her directly is unnecessary; she must be very busy (she's Romania's ambassador not only to Mexico but to practically *all* of Central America!) so surely her staff should know how and where I can get Romanian books, a scholarship, etc., but what can I do if none of them will tell me? And how should I refer to her--Your Excellency, or...?
My Romanian is awful (I've been studying online, unable to attend classes, for over a year; but I can understand it far more than I can speak it!), but since her staff completely changed their rude attitude (which they adopted when I spoke Spanish or English, with no provocation, I might add, since I was always very polite and friendly) when I made an attempt to speak to them in Romanian, perhaps she might also appreciate it...?

Please help! If she says yes, Mrs. Voicu will be the *only* really important person I've ever spoken to...Please help!
Creo que mi duda se puede resumir en: ¿cómo le hablo a la Embajadora Plenipotenciaria de Rumania a todos los países de Centroamérica? 
¡Gracias!
P.D. Mi lengua materna es el español latino, pero hablo el inglés como nativo.

Comment: You could have asked in spanish :) Podrías haber preguntado en español :)

Answer (score 1):

El tratamiento correcto para **dirigirse** a un embajador es **Sr. Embajador** / **Sra. Embajadora**.

En situaciones más formales que una audiencia personal (presentación de cartas credenciales, firma de tratados, etc.) se puede utilizar un tratamiento formal equivalente al de Ministro (al menos en España un embajador tiene el rango de Ministro Plenipotenciario de 1ª, 2ª o 3ª clase), es decir, **Su Excelencia**.

Nunca, jamás tratar de tú/vos, a menos que te lo pida expresamente.

Aparte, para **referirse** al embajador, se puede hablar de **El Sr. Embajador** / **La Sra. Embajadora** en el tono menos formal, **Su Excelencia el Embajador** / **Su Excelencia la Embajadora**, en un tono intermedio, y **El Excelentísimo Sr. Embajador `<apellido>`** / **El Excelentísimo Sr. `<apellido>`, Embajador de `<país>`** (y las correspondientes formas en femenino), en el escalón más formal.

Lo siguiente ya no es parte de lo que corresponde en Spanish.SE.C

Acerca de tu imagen personal, simplemente que sea cuidada, pero en cualquier caso sé tú mismo/tú misma.

Acerca del idioma, te recomendaría que saludaras y te presentaras en su idioma, como muestra de cortesía, y llevaras el resto de la conversación en un idioma que convenga a ambos, que viene a ser el español.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez, en una situación similar, me indicaron que debía dirigirme por escrito al embajador de España en Austria y quien me lo indicó (era personal de la embajada) especificó que la fórmula correcta para el tratamiento era **Excelentísimo Señor Embajador, Representante Permanente**.

Esta es la manera con la que un ciudadano español se dirige a un embajador de su propio país. Seguramente haya otra fórmula para la embajadora de Rumanía, y posíblemente les de un poco igual la manera como les escriba un ciudadano del país ante el que representa al suyo siempre y cuando sea un tratamiento correcto y respetuoso en el idioma local.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't you seen Cantinflas' movies?

It is possible your audition already happened, if not:
[image: a meme of popular "keep calm" poster]
Keep calm and address her as "***Su Excelencia***"

Comment: It looks a bit like a joke but I am serious, it has to do with culture, it is a standard protocol, chances are she is already way too familiar with that.